# InverseRadon behaves differently from iradon of MATLAB

Tags: image-processing, inverse, integral-transforms, matlab, scaling

I have to calculate a 2-dimensional radially symmetric distribution from a single projection.

I know that `InverseRadon` should actually do the job, but I get the wrong scaling and also the wrong spatial frequencies. I know that it is possible to define a filtering function for `InverseRadon` by choosing a method, e.g. by `Method -> (# &)`. Nevertheless, I tried quite many filter functions and never get the proper scaling or proper spatial frequencies.

In the following I have tried to find out what's wrong using one somewhat complex but well-defined radially symmetric function from which I generate the projection and then apply the inverse Radon on it:

```
komplFkt = 
  ArrayResample[
    Table[5 Cos[2π Sqrt[x^2+y^2]] - (x^2 + y^2) + 6,{x,-3,3,0.1},{y,-3,3,0.1}],
    {128, 128}];

projectionAlongYDir = Total/@komplFkt;

GraphicsRow[
  {ListPlot3D[komplFkt, PlotRange -> All], 
   Automatic,
   ColorFunction -> ArrayPlot[komplFkt, PlotLegends -> "TemperatureMap"],
   ListPlot[projectionAlongYDir, PlotLabel -> "Projection along Y-direction"]}]
```

which gives

[image: left and middle: radially symmetric example function/data, right: projected data along Y-direction]

*Left and middle: radially symmetric example function/data. Right: projected data along Y-direction*

Even though I have only a single projection, I know that for a radially symmetric function I should get always the same projection, even if I look at it from a different angle. That's why I construct now a "virtual" Radon transform of my original data, by simply repetitively placing my projected data into the columns of an image:

```
makeVirtaulRDNfromSingleProj[projectedDataList_] := 
Image @ Transpose @ ConstantArray[projectedDataList,Length[projectedDataList]];

makeVirtaulRDNfromSingleProj[projectionAlongYDir] // ImageAdjust
```

this gives then (watch out for the `// ImageAdjust`):

[image: 'virtual' Radon transform]

*"virtual" Radon transform*

Now I perform the backprojection, i.e. the `InverseRadon[]` on the previously generated 'virtual' transform (that I get from my measurements):

```
result = 
  InverseRadon[makeVirtaulRDNfromSingleProj[#], {Length @ #, Length @ #}] & @ projectionAlongYDir;

ArrayPlot[ImageData @ result, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

Which gives:

[image: recovered data from single projection]

*Recovered data from single projection*

As we can see, the scale is completely different than the function I started with. Moreover, when we look at the cross-sections through the middle (i.e. data's origin) we also see different spatial frequencies by calling the following functions:

```
GraphicsRow[
  {ListPlot[{komplFkt[[64]], (ImageData @ result)[[64]]},
     Joined -> True, 
     PlotLabel -> "unscaled cross-sections\nthrough center",
     PlotLegends -> {"original function", "after InverseRadon[]"}], 
   ListPlot[Rescale /@ {komplFkt[[64]], (ImageData @ result)[[64]]},
     Joined -> True, 
     PlotLabel -> "rescaled cross-sections\nthrough center",
     PlotLegends -> {"original function", "after InverseRadon[]"}]}]
```

[image: cross-sections through the center]

Tested in *Mathematica* *v11.3* and *v12.0*.

Just for comparison, I tried to do the same in MATLAB. Neglecting some small deviations in the middle and some larger deviations at the boundaries I get there almost the same cross section I would expect:

[image: corresponding problem solved in MATLAB]

Ok, the obvious answer is then probably: "do your calcs in MATLAB then". But why does *Mathematica's* `InverseRadon` behave so completely differently from `iradon`? Is it a bug?

I know that the default filter setting in *Mathematica* is `(1 + Cos[# Pi])/2&`.    Hann filter (default) and in MATLAB is Ram-Lak (which should correspond in *Mathematica* to setting of `Method -> (#&)`).

But no matter what kind of filters I apply in *Mathematica*, I don't get anywhere near the original data (which means the result is several magnitudes off).

I know this is not a MATLAB forum, but for completeness, I put here also my MATLAB code:

```matlab
numOfElts=128;
x=linspace(1,128,128);
startMat=zeros(numOfElts,numOfElts);
for i = 1:numOfElts
    for j = 1:numOfElts
        startmat(j,i) = 6+5*cos(2*pi*sqrt((3*(i-numOfElts/2-0.5)/(numOfElts/2))^2+(3*(j-numOfElts/2-0.5)/(numOfElts/2))^2))-(3*(i-numOfElts/2-0.5)/(numOfElts/2))^2-(3*(j-numOfElts/2-0.5)/(numOfElts    /2))^2;
        end
    end
middleVecOrigin=startmat(64,:);
orthoProj=sum(startmat);
virtualRDN=transpose(repmat(orthoProj,180,1));
quasiOriginalData = iradon(virtualRDN,0:179,128);

middleVecRes=quasiOriginalData(64,:);

figure
subplot(1,3,1)
contourf(startmat)
colorbar

subplot(1,3,2)
plot(x,middleVecOrigin,x,middleVecRes)
legend('original cross-section','inverse radon c.-s.')
subplot(1,3,3)
contourf(quasiOriginalData)
colorbar
```

Comment: "Flagged it now as bug, because no one responded with an answers since August 2020" - but did you report it to Support?

Comment: The frequency is easy to match, just pad the `projectionAlongYDir`: `makeVirtaulRDNfromSingleProj[projectedDataList_] := 
 Image@Transpose@
   ConstantArray[
    ArrayPad[projectedDataList, (Sqrt[2] - 1) Length[projectedDataList]/2 // Floor, 
     "Fixed"], Sqrt[2] Length[projectedDataList] // Floor]`.

Comment: @J.M. No I didn't report it as bug, since I wanted some interaction from the community first to make sure that, I haven't made a mistake of overlooking something ;-)

Comment: @xzczd: Thanks, that seems to work at least with the frequencies, but it doesn't get the amplitdues right.

Comment: Better to contact WRI for clarification. Currently the document does involve too little implementation detail for `InverseRadon`.

Comment: Actually the source code of `InverseRadon` can be checked with ``GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions@InverseRadon``. (The output is quite readable! ) But I'm not that familiar with the underlying math so it's a bit hard for me to go deeper.

Comment: BTW, can the source code of `iradon` be checked with e.g. `edit iradon`?

Answer (score 9):

As it explained in tutorials functions
[`Radon`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Radon.html)
and
[`InverseRadon`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseRadon.html)
are supposed to be used with images only and not with arbitrary matrix, array or list. Even direct use `ImageData[InverseRadon[Radon[Image[data]]]]` does not return `data` as it is, since `Radon` returns an image in which values are normalized so that the highest possible value is 1. Let see this example (as in Matlab code)

```
numOfElts = 128; startmat = ConstantArray[0, {numOfElts, numOfElts}];


Do[ 
 Do[
   startmat[[j, i]] = 
     6 + 5*Cos[
        2*Pi*Sqrt[(3*(i - numOfElts/2 - 0.5)/(numOfElts/
                 2))^2 + (3*(j - numOfElts/2 - 0.5)/(numOfElts/
                 2))^2]] - (3*(i - numOfElts/2 - 0.5)/(numOfElts/
            2))^2 - (3*(j - numOfElts/2 - 0.5)/(numOfElts/2))^2;, {j, 
    1, numOfElts}];, {i, 1, numOfElts}]
```

First we apply `Radon`, then `InverseRadon` and get this images

```
im0 = Image[startmat]
im0R = ImageResize[Radon[im0], {128, 128}]
 im1 = ImageResize[InverseRadon[im0R], {128, 128}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Therefore we can't return to `startmat`, and if we try compare cross section we need to use some scaling

```
ListPlot[{ImageData[im0][[64]], 
  ImageData[im1][[64]]}]

ListLinePlot[
 Rescale /@ {(ImageData@im0)[[64]], (ImageData@im1)[[64]]}]
```

[image: Figure 2]

The best scaling what I got with  @xzczd padding is not so differ from Matlab `iradon`, the corresponding code is given by

```
n = numOfElts = 2 128; startmat = 
 ConstantArray[0, {numOfElts, numOfElts}];

Do[ 
 Do[
   startmat[[j, i]] = 
     6 + 5*Cos[
        2*Pi*Sqrt[(3*(i - numOfElts/2 - 0.5)/(numOfElts/
                 2))^2 + (3*(j - numOfElts/2 - 0.5)/(numOfElts/
                 2))^2]] - (3*(i - numOfElts/2 - 0.5)/(numOfElts/
            2))^2 - (3*(j - numOfElts/2 - 0.5)/(numOfElts/2))^2;, {j, 
    1, numOfElts}];, {i, 1, numOfElts}];
orthoProj = Sum[startmat[[j]], {j, numOfElts}]; max = 
 Max[orthoProj]; min = Min[orthoProj]; uv = 
 ConstantArray[1, {Length[orthoProj]}];
makeVirtaulRDNfromSingleProj[projectedDataList_] := 
 Image@Transpose@
   ConstantArray[
    ArrayPad[
     projectedDataList, ((Sqrt[2] - 1) Length[projectedDataList]/2 // 
       Floor), "Fixed"], Sqrt[2] Length[projectedDataList] // Floor]

result = InverseRadon[makeVirtaulRDNfromSingleProj[#], {n, n}, 
     Method -> {(# &), "CutoffFrequency" -> .5}] &@orthoProj;

{ListPlot[Rescale /@ {startmat[[n/2]], ImageData[result][[n/2]]}, 
  Joined -> True, 
  PlotLabel -> "Rescaled cross-sections\nthrough center", 
  PlotLegends -> {"original function", "after InverseRadon[]"}],

ListPlot[{startmat[[n/2]], 
   Pi ((max - min) Rescale@(ImageData[result // ImageAdjust][[n/2]]) +
        min uv)/n}, Joined -> True, 
  PlotLabel -> "unscaled cross-sections\nthrough center", 
  PlotLegends -> {"original function", "after InverseRadon[]"}]}
```

[image: Figure 3]

The final step is to redefine `uv` so that it minimize difference of original function and `result`.

Comment: So, you think it's not possible to reproduce the behavior of `iradon` of MATLAB with `InverseRadon`?

Comment: @xzczd Actually we can and my example demonstrates how we should prepare image for `InverseRadon` with Radon method. Also we can't compare final result without scaling  since `InverseRadon` returns image, not array or matrix as `iradon` in Matlab.

Comment: @AlexTrounev This scaling is in my opinion an unnecessary operation, as even the MMa help for Radon transform uses AdjustImage[]. I need, however,  the absolute amplitude of the not known initial distribution. A further problem in my opinion is that the the scale factor depends on the number of sampling points in combination with the fact that for my problem it is necessary to do zero padding to recover the most important frequencies. But if the scale depends on the number of zeros used which changes the frequencies, I have a real problem in efficiently estimating an optimal number of zeros.

Comment: @Quit007 Probably your problem is not linked to `InverseRadon` directly, since this function has to be applied to images only. It looks like your problem is mostly mathematical problem.  In this regard your example with `komplFkt`  also not directly linked to your problem.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Of course komplFkt is only an example function, which, nevertheless, has the same symmetry than my actual problem. Maybe I just fail to see, why InverseRadon in Mma shouldn't be able to recover the absolute values - which is basically the task of inverse radon transforms used in life science e.g. phase contrast computer tomography for which it is essential to calculate the absolute value of the objects. This might be also caused by the fact that all scientific literature I have looked at dealt specifically with radon transforms restoring the absolute values.

Comment: The scaling is the gordian knot in my opinion. I tried for a while but failed to find an explicit formula for the rescaling. Do you manage to?

Comment: @Quit007 Can you give a link to some paper with algorithm to restore absolute value?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Of course, a good point to start is (I think) e.g. Kak and Slaney: http://www.slaney.org/pct/pct-toc.html The problem with the scaling, and frequencies-reproduction is adressed in Chapter 3 (3.3.3 on page 70 ff.)

Comment: @AlexTrounev  There are also fast discrete implementations that have an exact inverse: https://www.pnas.org/content/103/51/19249  They show that (though iteratively) the inverse Radon gives the exact color map. (see the supportive Figs too)  And these guys here: https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/060650301  show that the discrete Radon transform and its inverse converge for high pixel numbers towards the continuouus Radon transform.

Comment: @Quit007 Thank you for paper links. I will try to implement the William H. Press algorithm for discrete Radon.

Comment: @xzczd I have got something similar to `iradon` with your padding. See update to my answer.

Comment: @Alex Trounev: Well, regarding the discrete transform I was able to set that up. My problem is just the run-time. Even compiled the run-time is far longer than the matlab version. Of course, I can post my version down below, so you needn't start from scratch

Answer (score 7):

As this has come up in the comments, somebody might be interested at least in the discrete version as described here: [discrete radon transform](https://www.pnas.org/content/103/51/19249):

getRadonLinesComped[] is the (compiled) function that extracts the discrete lines from the image. The uncompiled version is getRadonLines[].

```
(*rekursive Funktion, die aus einer Steigung und Vektorlänge Daten \
für eine entprechende "digital line" generiert*)
calcSlopeRLAndMiddleElem[structure_(*structure \[Equal] {slope_,
  oldVectorSize_(odd Number),...other stuff*)] := {(*total slope in \
the new halves*)(structure[[1]] - Mod[structure[[1]], 2])/2,
  (*length of new halves*)(structure[[2]] - 1)/
   2,(*Value of the middle element*)Mod[structure[[1]], 2]}

(*erzeugt die Steigungspunkte für eine "digital line" für eine \
gesamtsteigung und eine Bildgröße
ACHTUNG Bildgröße muss sein: 2^Nx2^N *)
constructDLine[totalSlope_, imgWidth_] := Module[{recursiveStruct},
  (*Die Rekursion erfolgt solange, 
  bis die Länge der Subliste 1 ist  \[Rule] #[[2]]>1&.*)
  recursiveStruct = 
   Drop[NestWhileList[
     calcSlopeRLAndMiddleElem, {totalSlope, 
      imgWidth - 1}, #[[2]] > 1 &], 1];
  (*structure of recursiveStruct is as follows:
  {{total slope in the new halves,length of new halves,
  value of the middle element which is not in any one of the \
halves}},...}
  *)
  (*Das hier würde den parametrischen y-
  Verlauf der Linien im Bild ergeben:
   Accumulate@Prepend[makeSlopeList[recursiveStruct],0]
  *)
  (*das hier gibt den relativen Anstieg der Linien im Bild:*)
  Prepend[makeSlopeList[recursiveStruct], 0]
  ]

(*erzeugt aus den Daten in recursiveResultStruct die \
"Steigungspunkte" einer "digital line"*)
makeSlopeList[recursiveResultStruct_] := 
 Module[{startingList, elementaryList, middleElements},
  startingList = ConstantArray[recursiveResultStruct[[-1, 1]], 3];
  elementaryList = 
   ReplacePart[startingList, 2 -> recursiveResultStruct[[-1, -1]]];
  (*extrahiert die Mittenelemente und ordnet sie aufsteigend*)
  middleElements = 
   Reverse[#[[3]] & /@ Drop[recursiveResultStruct, -1]];
  (*das hier erzeugt aus den mittenelementen die Gesamtliste*)
  Fold[Join[#1, {#2}, #1] &, elementaryList, middleElements]
  ]

parametricDLines[totalSlope_, imgWidth_, yOffset_] := Module[{},
  Transpose[{Range[imgWidth], 
    1 + Accumulate@constructDLine[totalSlope, imgWidth] + yOffset}]
  ]

getRadonLines[imgData_] := 
 Module[{grayImg, bild0, tempImg, imgWidth, tempImgData, offsetVar, 
   dLineDef, offset, radonData},
  (*Operationen für den Fall, dass der Input ein Bild ist:
  (*das eigentliche Bild wird unten und oben mit einem 0-
  Bild gepaddet*)
  grayImg=ColorConvert[#,"Grayscale"]&@img;
  bild0=0 grayImg;
  tempImg=ImageAssemble[{{bild0},{grayImg}, {bild0}}];
  imgWidth=ImageDimensions[img][[1]];
  tempImgData=Transpose@ImageData@tempImg;*)
  imgWidth = Dimensions[imgData][[1]];

  (*Möglichkeit zur Anpassung des Prozesses:
  tempImgData=Transpose@Join[0 imgData,imgData,0 imgData];  
  ist näher am Originalpaper, 
  verursacht aber bei der Rücktrafo einen zum Rand anteigenden "Kegel".
  tempImgData=Transpose@Join[imgData,imgData,imgData]; 
  Verursacht keinen ansteigenden Kegel
  *)
  (*tempImgData=Transpose@Join[0 imgData,imgData,0 imgData];*)
  tempImgData = Transpose@Join[imgData, imgData, imgData];
  (*Funktionstest mit: \[Rule] Input: getRadonLines[ImageResize[
  testImg1,64]] ;
  dLineDef=parametricDLines[30,imgWidth,offsetVar];
  Image@Reverse@Table[Extract[tempImgData,
  dLineDef/.(offsetVar\[Rule]offset)],{offset,2 imgWidth,1,-1}]
  *)

  radonData = Table[
    dLineDef = parametricDLines[slope, imgWidth, offsetVar];
    (*das Extract extrahiert die Datenwerte entlang einer digital \
line. Das Table enthält deshalb diese Linieneinträge zeilenweise. 
    Die Summe über jede Zeile erfolgt daher mit Total/@*)
    Total /@ 
     Table[Extract[tempImgData, 
       dLineDef /. (offsetVar -> offset)], {offset, 2 imgWidth, 1, -1}]
    , {slope, 0, imgWidth - 1}];
  (*das Reverse@Transpose@ bewirkt eine Anordnung so, 
  dass die Radontrafo mit erster Spalte den Winkel 0 hat, 
  letzte Spalte den Winkel 45\[Degree] und das Bild aufrecht unten \
steht*)
  (*1/imgWidth*) Reverse@Transpose@radonData
  ]

getRadonLinesComped = 
 Compile[{{imgData, _Real, 2}}, 
  Module[{grayImg, bild0, tempImg, imgWidth, tempImgData, offsetVar, 
    dLineDef, offset, radonData,
    arrayLength, i, structure, temp, recursiveStruct,
    startingList, elementaryList, middleElements, slopeList, 
    tempSlope, tempSize, tempMiddle,
    xVals, rawDlineShape},

   imgWidth = Dimensions[imgData][[1]];

   tempImgData =(*Transpose@*)Join[imgData, imgData, imgData];
   (*Funktionstest mit: \[Rule] Input: getRadonLines[ImageResize[
   testImg1,64]] ;
   dLineDef=parametricDLines[30,imgWidth,offsetVar];
   Image@Reverse@Table[Extract[tempImgData,
   dLineDef/.(offsetVar\[Rule]offset)],{offset,2 imgWidth,1,-1}]
   *)

   arrayLength = Log2[imgWidth] - 1;
   xVals = Range[imgWidth];
   radonData = Table[
     tempSlope = slope;
     tempSize = imgWidth - 1;
     tempMiddle = tempSlope;
     recursiveStruct = ConstantArray[0, {arrayLength, 3}];
     i = 1;
     While[tempSize > 1 ,
      tempMiddle = Mod[tempSlope, 2];
      tempSlope = Round[(tempSlope - Mod[tempSlope, 2])/2];
      tempSize = Quotient[(tempSize - 1), 2];
      recursiveStruct[[i]] = {tempSlope, tempSize, tempMiddle};
      i++;
      ];
     (*recursiveStruct wird korrekt aufgebaut!*)
     
     startingList = ConstantArray[recursiveStruct[[-1, 1]], 3];
     elementaryList = {startingList[[1]], recursiveStruct[[-1, -1]], 
       startingList[[1]]};
     (*extrahiert die Mittenelemente und ordnet sie aufsteigend*)
     middleElements = Reverse[#[[3]] & /@ Drop[recursiveStruct, -1]];
     (*das hier erzeugt aus den mittenelementen die Gesamtliste*)
     slopeList = 
      Fold[Join[#1, {#2}, #1] &, elementaryList, middleElements];
     rawDlineShape = 1 + Accumulate@Prepend[slopeList, 0];
     
        Total /@ Table[
            
       tempImgData[[rawDlineShape[[z]] + offset, 
        xVals[[z]]]], {offset, 2 imgWidth, 1, -1}, {z, imgWidth}]
     , {slope, 0, imgWidth - 1}];
   Reverse@Transpose@radonData
   (*
   radonData=Table[
   (*das Extract extrahiert die Datenwerte entlang einer digital \
  line. Das Table enthält deshalb diese Linieneinträge zeilenweise. 
   Die Summe über jede Zeile erfolgt daher mit Total/@*)
   Total/@Table[Extract[tempImgData,
   Transpose[{Range[imgWidth],1+ Accumulate@constructDLineComped[
   slope,imgWidth]+offsetVar}]
   ],{offset,2 imgWidth,1,-1}]
   ,{slope,0,imgWidth-1}];
   (*das Reverse@Transpose@ bewirkt eine Anordnung so, 
   dass die Radontrafo mit erster Spalte den Winkel 0 hat, 
   letzte Spalte den Winkel 45\[Degree] und das Bild aufrecht unten \
  steht*)
   (*1/imgWidth*) Reverse@Transpose@radonData*)
   ], RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True, 
     CompilationTarget -> "C"];
```

the Radon data from an image can be determined then by this function, where imgData is the matrix containing the image data:

```
backProjection[radonData_] := 
 Module[{imgWidth, height, transRDNdata, dLineDef, orthogonalProj, 
   dLineJumps, backProjectedData, slope},
  {height, imgWidth} = Dimensions[radonData];
  transRDNdata = Transpose[radonData];

  backProjectedData = Sum[
    (*das hier bestimmt die Orte, 
    an denen die Matrix getiltet werden muss*)
    dLineDef = parametricDLines[slope, imgWidth, 0];
    (*das hier erzeugt eine Seed Matrix aus den zeilenweisen \
Projektionen der Radon-Transformierten des Objekts.
    Der Zeileneintrag wird hier verschmiert und deshalb müsste der \
Wert im "Schmierer" 1/imgWidth betragen, 
    aber diese Operation wird später durchgeführt.*)
    orthogonalProj = ConstantArray[transRDNdata[[slope]], imgWidth];
    dLineJumps = Transpose[dLineDef][[2]];
    Do[orthogonalProj = 
      MapAt[RotateRight[#, dLineJumps[[i]] - 1] &, orthogonalProj, 
       i], {i, 2, imgWidth}];
    orthogonalProj
    , {slope, imgWidth}];
  1/imgWidth^2 Transpose@(Take[#, -imgWidth] & /@ backProjectedData)    
  ]


discreteRadonC[imgData_] := 
 Module[{averageImgBrightness, radonInitImgs, radonInitData, 
   radonDataSet, rawBackProjectionData, correctedBPdata, finalBP},
  (*erzuegt die verschiedenen Geometrien, 
  die für die diskrete Radon Trafo mittels digital lines benötigt \
werden*)
  (*falls der Input ein Bild ist, 
  kann das durch folgenden Code bewerkstelligt werden:
  radonInitImgs={#,ImageRotate@#,ImageReflect@#,ImageRotate@
  ImageReflect@#}&@img;
  radonDataSet=getRadonLines/@ImageData/@radonInitImgs;
  *)
  (*falls der Input ein DatenArray ist, 
  wird das durch folgenden Code bewerkstelligt:*)
  radonInitData = {#, Reverse@Transpose@#, Reverse@#, 
      Reverse@Transpose@Reverse@#} &@(imgData);
  (*ArrayPlot[#,PlotLegends\[Rule]Automatic]&/@radonDataSet*)
  radonDataSet = ParallelMap[getRadonLinesComped, radonInitData];
  radonDataSet
  ]
```

The backtransform function is this one:

```
discreteRadonBackProject[radonDataSet_] := 
 Module[{averageImgBrightness, radonInitImgs, radonInitData, 
   rawBackProjectionData, correctedBPdata, finalBP},
  (*erzuegt die verschiedenen Geometrien, 
  die für die diskrete Radon Trafo mittels digital lines benötigt \
werden*)
  (*falls der Input ein Bild ist, 
  kann das durch folgenden Code bewerkstelligt werden:
  radonInitImgs={#,ImageRotate@#,ImageReflect@#,ImageRotate@
  ImageReflect@#}&@img;
  radonDataSet=getRadonLines/@ImageData/@radonInitImgs;
  *)
  (*averageImgBrightness=Mean[Flatten[imgData]];
  (*falls der Input ein DatenArray ist, 
  wird das durch folgenden Code bewerkstelligt:*)
  radonInitData={#,Reverse@Transpose@#,Reverse@#,Reverse@Transpose@
  Reverse@#}&@(imgData-0 averageImgBrightness);
  radonDataSet=getRadonLines/@radonInitData;
  (*ArrayPlot[#,PlotLegends\[Rule]Automatic]&/@radonDataSet*)
  *)

  rawBackProjectionData = backProjection /@ radonDataSet;
  (*ArrayPlot[#,PlotLegends\[Rule]Automatic]&/@
  rawBackProjectionData*)

  correctedBPdata = {#[[1]], Transpose@Reverse@#[[2]], Reverse@#[[3]],
       Reverse@Transpose@Reverse@#[[4]]} &@rawBackProjectionData;
  (*ArrayPlot[#,PlotLegends\[Rule]Automatic]&/@correctedBPdata*)

  finalBP = 1/4  Total[correctedBPdata];
  (*{ArrayPlot/@radonDataSet,ArrayPlot/@correctedBPdata}*)

  finalBP
  ]
```

The exact inverse is then found by a multi-grid approach with these functions:

```
shrinkArrays[arrayList_] := 
  ArrayResample[#, 1/2 Dimensions[#]] & /@ (1./4 arrayList);
enlargeArray[array_] := ArrayResample[array, 2 Dimensions[array]];

sharpening[array_] := 
 ListConvolve[{{-1./16, -1./8, -1./16}, {-1./8, 
    3./4, -1./8}, {-1./16, -1./8, -1./16}}, array, 1, 0]

approxRadonInverseByFullMultiGrid[radonData_] := 
 Module[{i = 1, numOfDownRecursions, initialBackTransform, 
   shrunkResidual, forwardList, approxSolutions, finalApproxSol},
  numOfDownRecursions = Log2[Dimensions[radonData[[1]]][[2]]];
  initialBackTransform = discreteRadonBackProject[radonData];
  forwardList = {initialBackTransform};
  shrunkResidual = radonData;
  While[i <= numOfDownRecursions - 2,
   {(*shrunkResidual=shrinkArrays[shrunkResidual-discreteRadon[
    forwardList[[1]]]];*)
    shrunkResidual = 
     shrinkArrays[shrunkResidual - discreteRadonC[forwardList[[1]]]];
    PrependTo[forwardList, 
     sharpening@discreteRadonBackProject[shrunkResidual]];
    i++;}
   ];
  (*forwardList=NestList[{shrinkArrays[#[[1]]-discreteRadon[#[[2]]]],
  sharpening@discreteRadonBackProject[shrinkArrays[#[[1]]-
  discreteRadon[#[[2]]]]]}&,{radonData(*f^h*),initialBackTransform(*u^
  h*)},numOfDownRecursions-2];
  approxSolutions=Reverse@Transpose[forwardList][[2]];
  finalApproxSol=Fold[#2+enlargeArray[#1]&,approxSolutions]*)
  Fold[#2 + enlargeArray[#1] &, forwardList]
  ]

(*approximation by iterative comparison of \
radon[radonInversed[approximation]] to original radon data*)
approxRadonInverseFMG[radonData_, numOfIterations_] := 
 Module[{initialBackTransform, resList},
  initialBackTransform = approxRadonInverseByFullMultiGrid[radonData];
  resList = 
   NestList[# + 
      approxRadonInverseByFullMultiGrid[
       radonData - discreteRadonC[#]] &, initialBackTransform, 
    numOfIterations];
  resList
  ]

convergenceCheck[initialImgData_, improvementDataList_] := 
 StandardDeviation[Flatten[(-initialImgData + #)]] & /@ 
  improvementDataList
```

For testing I have used these functions with this image:

[image]
It is necessary that the actual image is just single channel (e.g. grayscale) and the size is NxN with N~2^k with k an integer, e.g. defined as:
`ImageData@ImageResize[ColorConvert[(*image here*), "Grayscale"],{128,128}]`

```
DRTC256 = discreteRadonC[startImgData2];
ArrayPlot[#, PlotLegends -> Automatic] & /@ DRTC256
```

[image]

400 iterations are calculated for the approximate backtransform and every 80th is plotted

```
t1 = AbsoluteTime[];
iterTest64 = approxRadonInverseFMG[DRTC64, 400];
t2 = AbsoluteTime[];
Print[(t2 - t1)/3600. "h"];
ArrayPlot[#, PlotLegends -> Automatic] & /@ 
 iterTest64[[1 ;; 400 ;; 80]]
```

[image]

Depending on the size of the initial image size there is a iteration number dependent minimum of the residual error.
Unfortunately, with this discrete version (besides the fact that this is quite slow) I wasn't able to calculate the virtual (discrete) radon transform of the single backprojection of my radially symmetric problem I have described in my above question. And that's why the discrete transform doesn't really work for my problem.

Comment: I'm now with a mobile phone so can't check further, but what if you use `Table` instead of `ConstantArray` in `Compile`?

Comment: Function `backProjection` is not defined. Also function `getRadonLinesComped` is not really compiled to "C" due to several errors. What version you are run on?

Comment: @xzczd I don't know if that would be faster. The compiled function is anyways based on non-compiled one which I have written and tested before trying to compile it. If you like I can post it too

Comment: @AlexTrounev I'm sorry, I forgot to include some of the function. I have updated my post with (hopefully now complete set of) functions

Comment: @Quit007 Thanks for update, but function `backProjection` is not defined yet.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Again sorry, now BackProjection is now too posted

Comment: @Quit007 In the function definition `discreteRadonBackProject[radonDataSet_]` on the line `rawBackProjectionData = backProjection /@ radonDataSet;` the function `backProjection` is not defined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122633/discussion-between-quit007-and-alex-trounev).

Comment: How are `startImgData2` and `DRTC64` defined?

Comment: @xzczd basicaly the same way as DRTC256 = discreteRadonC[startImgData2]; --> DRTC64 = discreteRadonC[startImgData2];  The 64 instead of 256 refers to the size of startImgData2. After Alex Trounev replied that the code didn't work I ran mine again, especially the part with the approximate back-reconstruction. But with 256 x 256 image size the computation time was 1,5 h so, in my haste I switched to an image of 64x64 to test whether or not my code still works.

Comment: How is `startImgData2` generated? `ImageData@(*image here*)` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @xzczd ImageData@ImageResize[ColorConvert[(*image here*), "Grayscale"],{128,128}]    It is necessary that the actual image is just single channel (e.g. grayscale) and the size is NxN with N~2^k with k an integer

Comment: @Quit007 It's better to clarify all these in the answer.

Comment: This code not solves the problem of 2-dimensional radially symmetric distribution reconstruction from a single projection calculation and also it has no any advantage against `Radon` and `InverseRadon`.  Nevertheless it is good that Quit007 made this efforts (+1). May be we need next bounty with 1000 points to solve this problem:)